# how to display image from <img src> html tags from api?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have used `holder.txtTitle.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(dataList.getDescription(), 0));`

HtmlCompat.fromHtml removed tags but didn't displayed image

[I'm getting something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmHOe.png)

how to display the entire image instead of the box? because HtmlCompat.fromHtml didn't work.

thanks in advance

HTML text(from API):

```
 <p>Android is a Linux based operating system it is designed primarily for touch screen mobile devices such as smart phones and tablet computers. The operating system have developed a lot in last 15 years starting from black and white phones to recent smart phones or mini computers. One of the most widely used mobile OS &nbsp; these days is android. &nbsp;The android is software that was founded in Palo Alto of California in 2003.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="http://mapi.trycatchtech.com/uploads/android_tutorials/bf029f4a311b3168e0cfda1a0ef78815.png" style="height:342px; width:500px" /></p>

<p>The android is a powerful operating system and it supports large number of applications in Smartphones. These applications are more comfortable and advanced for the users. The hardware that supports android software is based on ARM architecture platform. The android is an open source operating system means that it&rsquo;s free and any one can use it. The android has got millions of apps available that can help you managing your life one or other way and it is available low cost in market at that reasons android is very popular.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="http://mapi.trycatchtech.com/uploads/android_tutorials/666b3ec86e308cd3e7f6bb1d12bb06f2.png" style="height:316px; width:508px" /></p>

<p>The android development supports with the full java programming language. Even other packages that are API and JSE are not supported. The first version 1.0 of android development kit (SDK) was released in 2008 and latest updated version is jelly bean.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load image of html in `TextView`. Make it `WebView`. Then load html text like `holder.webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,dataList.getDescription(),"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");`

Comment: activity become blank?nothing loaded?what's the issue..why it became blank?

Comment: Can you share your html text here?

Comment: hello shafayat ... I have added html api text..have a look

Comment: hey it worked ..instead of card view .I used relative layout ...thanks a lot shafayat ...I will ask more problems later..

Comment: images displayed so big...I need to scroll to the right  to view full images..is there a way to minimise it?

Comment: You can change image size by changing image size of `<img>` tag in the html response of API.

Comment: okay ...I will do that ...thanks..I will ask more problems later..:)

Comment: Hello shafayat... I have one problem..please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490130/data-is-not-getting-displayed-in-retrofit/59491000#59491000

Comment: hello shafayat...I need your help in here--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526045/how-to-run-java-and-xml-code-fetched-from-api-into-another-fragment

Comment: Sorry I've no experience on this.

Comment: hello shafayat..i need your help over here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071359/error-response-500-is-not-getting-diaplayed-when-password-and-confirm-password-t

Answer (score 0):

you should use html in your rest api response in webView
`val htmlText="your html"
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/abc.html");`