# Error Response 500 is not getting diaplayed when password and confirm password typed wrong

Tags: android, validation, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

my response getting successfully displayed when password and confirm password typed right....but when it mismatched it is not going to else part....not showing toast anything......please guide me ...need help...thanks in advance

here is my response when password and confirm password typed wrong in postman:-

```
{
"status": 500,
"message": "Could not reset password.",
"error": {
    "confirm_password": {
        "compareWith": "Passwords mismatch."
    }
},
"user_msg": "Could not reset password, please try again."
}
```

**here is my data classes:-**

1-->

```
data class Reset_Reponse_Base (
@SerializedName("status") val status : Int,
@SerializedName("message") val message : String,
@SerializedName("error") val error : Reset_Response_error,
@SerializedName("user_msg") val user_msg : String
)
```

2-->

```
 data class Reset_Response_error (
@SerializedName("confirm_password") val confirm_password : Reset_Response_Confirm_password

 )
```

3-->

```
data class Reset_Response_Confirm_password (
@SerializedName("compareWith") val compareWith : String
 )
```

**My response call activity:--->**

```
 var old_password = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.old_password)
    var new_password = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.new_password)
    var confirm_password =
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.confirm_new_password)
    val resetpwdbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.resetpwdbtn)
    resetpwdbutton.setOnClickListener {
        val old = old_password.text.toString().trim()
        val new = new_password.text.toString().trim()
        val confirm = confirm_password.text.toString().trim()
       
        val token: String =
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(
                applicationContext
            ).user.access_token.toString()
        RetrofitClient.instance.resetpassword(token, old, new, confirm)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<Reset_Reponse_Base> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Reset_Reponse_Base>, t: Throwable) {

                    Log.d("res", "" + t)


                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<Reset_Reponse_Base>,
                    response: Response<Reset_Reponse_Base>
                ) {
                    var res = response

                    if (res.body()?.status == 200) {

                        Log.d("response check ", "" + response.body()?.status.toString())
                        if (res.body()?.status == 200) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    applicationContext,
                            res.body()?.user_msg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                            Log.d("kjsfgxhufb", response.body()?.user_msg.toString())
                         

                        } else  if (res.body()?.status == 500){
                            val ret: Reset_Response_error = res.body()!!.error
                            val ret2: Reset_Response_Confirm_password = ret.confirm_password
                            //confused over here-->
                            //toast is not getting diaplayed when password and confirm password doesnt match
                            try {
                                val jObjError =
                                    JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    applicationContext,
                                    jObjError.getString("message")+jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show()
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                Log.e("errorrr",e.message)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

After replacing this `else  if (res.body()?.status == 500)` by `else if (!res.isSuccessful` ==> false in debugger

[image]

but if i do this-->`else if (res.errorBody()?.equals(500)!!)`

im getting this -->

[image]

### which is good but how can i access under this `[size=176 text={"status":500,"message":"Could not reset password.","error":{"co…]`  i have error message under error under content

i want to retrive ==> message":"Could not reset password."error":{"co…...

Comment: Did you check if `response.isSuccessful` is true or not?

Comment: @shafayathossain im not getting success when pwd and confirm pwd typed wrong

Comment: Then you cannot get error responses in this way. You have to parse error body. Example can be found here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling

Comment: @shafayathossain just look at the edited question

Comment: nothing wrong with your code if you are getting response like this. Check your credentials and verify it from your server.

Comment: @Wini That's why you have to parse error body. I've given a link in my previous comment. It will help you parse error body.

Comment: thanks @shafayathossain link really worked..thanks though...if you could make this as answer..i will upvote you :)

Comment: @shafayathossain here is my next question -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63114801/how-should-i-fetch-images-under-the-array-using-retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse error body. Following code will help you to parse error.

You can create your custom error class, so that you can do things for specific error type. Two exception class can be as following:

```
open class APIError: Exception() {
    private val statusCode = 0
    fun status(): Int {
        return statusCode
    }

    fun message(): String? {
        return message
    }
}

class UnknownError : APIError() {}
```

Error parser class can be as following. I've used here kotling extension function to use it easily.

```
fun Response<*>.parseError(): Throwable {
    val converter: Converter<ResponseBody, APIError?> = RetrofitClient.instance
            .responseBodyConverter(APIError::class.java, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))
    val error: APIError?
    error = try {
        if(errorBody() != null) {
            converter.convert(errorBody())
        } else {
            return UnknownError("Something wrong")
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        return APIError()
    }
    return Throwable(error)
}
```

And finally in retrofit `onResponse()` method, you can do this:

```
RetrofitClient.instance.resetpassword(token, old, new, confirm)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<Reset_Reponse_Base> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Reset_Reponse_Base>, t: Throwable) {

                    Log.d("res", "" + t)


                }

                override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<Reset_Reponse_Base>,
                        response: Response<Reset_Reponse_Base>
                ) {
                    var res = response
                    if(response.isSuccessful) {
                        if (res.body().status == 200) {

                            Log.d("response check ", "" + response.body()?.status.toString())
                            if (res.body()?.status == 200) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        applicationContext,
                                        res.body()?.user_msg,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show()
                                Log.d("kjsfgxhufb", response.body()?.user_msg.toString())


                            } else if (res.body()?.status == 500) {
                                val ret: Reset_Response_error = res.body()!!.error
                                val ret2: Reset_Response_Confirm_password = ret.confirm_password
                                //confused over here-->
                                //toast is not getting diaplayed when password and confirm password doesnt match
                                try {
                                    val jObjError =
                                            JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            applicationContext,
                                            jObjError.getString("message") + jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                } catch (e: Exception) {
                                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                    Log.e("errorrr", e.message)
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        val error = res.parseError()
                        // do your stuffs with error
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: hey need help in here -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224711/kotlin-typecastexception-null-cannot-be-cast-to-non-null-type-kotlin-collection

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you need to read the Error ResponseBody

```
    val errorBodyBuffer = Buffer()
    res.errorBody()?.writeTo(errorBodyBuffer)
    val errorBodyString = errorBodyBuffer.clone().readUtf8()
```

Now you can use Gson or JsonObject to parse the `errorBodyString`

Comment: no still not working ..im getting null in body==>using debugger...

Comment: what's the exception message ?

Comment: i got the answer from shafayat shared the link above ..thanks for your quick response:)

Answer (score 0):

don't check the body response error code check for

```
if(response.code() == 500){
  val errorBody = response.errorBody()
  val json = JSONObject(errorBody)
  //show toast
}
```

Comment: i not getting toast at all...during debugging im getting as second image which i showed above............my response is under content of errorbody if you seee......how can i retreive that????

Comment: it's inside errorBody() you should get if you call response.errorBody(), just check for code

Comment: i have used this only --> l response.errorBody() .....still the situation is same

Comment: can you change this line as well (res.body()?.status == 500) to res.code()==500 in your if condition

Comment: the thing is that body is itself null how you can check for status code if the whole body is null

Comment: so try to use the res.code()==500 to check the error scenario then it will enter into the else if condition

Comment: i have used this only `res.code()==500 ` in my code ...its just that i have not updated the question above :)\

Comment: it''s getting inside the else if condition but you are not able to access the errorBody?

Comment: yes exactly ....as you see my second image ...reponse is under the content under errorbody

Comment: there is one possibility that you are consuming the error response at first place that might be the reason it's not available in second one. since it's a buffer and might be getting exhaust after calling at first place. check once by debugging

Comment: also check if you are able to get the error body by calling  response?.errorBody()?.bytes().toString()

Comment: type mismatched required boolean but found string

Comment: hey need help in here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149093/how-do-i-post-long-encoded-string-of-base64-image-to-server-using-retrofit