# I am trying to call one servlet to another servlet, unable to call servlet

Tags: java

I have build the code for jdbc-Servlet, I made jdbc connection for Data retrieving.Now I want to call servlet,How do I call one Servlet to another Servlet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute multiple servlets in sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024949/how-do-i-execute-multiple-servlets-in-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RequestDispatcher](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");
//Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file,
// or HTML file) on the server.
rd.forward(request,response)

//Includes the content of a resource (servlet, JSP page, HTML file) in the response.
rd.include(request,response)
```

Comment: hello sumit singh..can you help me over here--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526045/how-to-run-java-and-xml-code-fetched-from-api-into-another-fragment ...