# Property declaration paradigm under Android's Java

Tags: java, android, properties

I have visited many references regarding the simple question -
how to declare a property under Android Java.
All of the examples I found do not eliminate compiler's errors..
Please, help me to save my time, give me the analog of the C# properties but under Android Java.

```
Class A {
    protected bool bField = false;
    public bool BField { get { return bField; } set { bField = value; }
```

// and

```
    public bool AField { get; set; }
```

}

Thanks

Comment: could you form out your reply as the answer and I'll  mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "properties" in Java (not as far as the compiler is concerned, anyway). A C# property translates into 3 three things in Java - a private field, a getter and a setter method.

So a property like this in C#:

```
public bool AField { get; set; }
```

would translate to the following in Java:

```
private boolean aField;

public boolean getAField() { return aField; }

public void setAField(boolean aField) { this.aField = aField; }
```

(Actually, for a boolean field, the getter usually has the prefix `is`, e.g. `isHidden`, `isEnabled` etc. but here `isAField` sounds weird)

Comment: hi..Sweeper ..can you help me out her -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526045/how-to-run-java-and-xml-code-fetched-from-api-into-another-fragment